# C# Web API - POST with ID only

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have an endpoint that clones a record but to do this I only need to use an Id. Since I only need to use an Id I've written this endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test/clone/{id}")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, description: "Clone an existing record", type: typeof(int))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Clone(int id)
{
    var newId = _service.DoSomething(id);
    return Ok(newId);
}
```

I then want to call this endpoint in a test but I don't know how to write this:

```
 var result =
            await WebServer.HttpClient.PostAsync($"test/clone/{id}", // WHAT GOES HERE??) 

  var newId = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<int>();
```

Does anyone know how I can call this endpoint using HttpClient??

Comment: If you want to be RESTful, then you should probably have a GET method that creates the clone, and then a POST method that allows you to save the newly created clone. That clone would be `WHAT GOES HERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass `null` and it will send it with no body
e.g.

```
 var result =
            await WebServer.HttpClient.PostAsync($"test/clone/{id}", null)
```

Comment: Won't this cause a problem because the API is expecting an int and you're sending it null?

Comment: No because he is passing the `id` as part of the route and not the body